# How to hide menu in Combobox if the search value is empty Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a simple Combobox component

And I want it to hide the menu part when the input is empty (so when a match is not found).
And to show it again when the match is found.
I wan unable to find anything in props of combobox and menu in the docs.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
<v-combobox
            v-model="select"
            :items="states"
            :search-input.sync="search"
            label="Select a favorite activity or create a new one"
></v-combobox>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      select: 'Any value',
      search: null,
      items: [],
      states: [
        'Alabama',
        'Alaska',
        'American Samoa',
        'Arizona',
        'Arkansas',
        'California',
        'Colorado',
      ]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    search (val) {
      if(val && val !== this.select) {
        this.querySelections(val)
      } else {
        console.log(val)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    querySelections (v) {
      // Simulated ajax query
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.items = this.states.filter(e => {
          return (e || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((v || '').toLowerCase()) > -1
        })
      }, 500)
    }
  }
})
```

**UPDATE**

I think I found the solution

I added  `:menu-props="{value: autoselectMenu}"` to the combobox then I created `autoselectMenu: false` property in my data. And in my watcher I did this

```
search (val) {
      if(val && val !== this.select) {
        this.querySelections(val)
        this.autoselectMenu = true
      } else if(!val) {
        this.autoselectMenu = false
      }
    }
```

[Link](https://codepen.io/Allan11/pen/yWaRVO)

Comment: Btw, don't update your pen which demonstrates the problem, rather create a fork and then save the solution in the fork, and let original codepen remain for posterity. Also answer should be in the answer section, not an edit of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass custom value of `value` prop in `menu-props` attribute, so just set it to false when your `search` is empty, and don't pass it so it preserves default behaviour:

```
<v-combobox :menu-props="menuProps"

// ... 

computed: {
  menuProps() {
    return !this.search ? {value: false} : {}
  }
},
```

**EDIT**
One line:

```
<v-combobox :menu-props="{ ...(!search && {value:false}) }"
```

Comment: For other people using this; if you need to combine it with other menu props, the computed property seemed to be more reliable, I had issues accomplishing it with the oneliner.